# Deprecated features from jquery 1.8.0

Tags: jquery

This code works with jQuery 1.8.0 but not with the newer versions like 1.11.0. Which features used by it are deprecated and how can I make it work? I looked at the documentation but couldn't find in this code any feature in the deprecated list.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

// Icon Click Focus
$('div.icon').click(function(){
    $('input#search').focus();
});

// Live Search
// On Search Submit and Get Results
function search() {
    var query_value = $('input#search').val();
    $('b#search-string').html(query_value);
    if(query_value !== ''){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../includes/search.php",
            data: { query: query_value },
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                $("ul#results").html(html);
            }
        });
    }return false;    
}

$("input#search").live("keyup", function(e) {
    // Set Timeout
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));

    // Set Search String
    var search_string = $(this).val();

    // Do Search
    if (search_string == '') {
        $("ul#results").fadeOut();
        $('h4#results-text').fadeOut();
    }else{
        $("ul#results").fadeIn();
        $('h4#results-text').fadeIn();
        $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(search, 100));
    };
});

});
```

Comment: [.live() was deprecated in 1.7](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**'live'** has been deprecated. Instead of 'live' use 'on'.

```
$("input#search").on("keyup", function(e) {
    // Set Timeout
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));

    // Set Search String
    var search_string = $(this).val();

    // Do Search
    if (search_string == '') {
        $("ul#results").fadeOut();
        $('h4#results-text').fadeOut();
    }else{
        $("ul#results").fadeIn();
        $('h4#results-text').fadeIn();
        $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(search, 100));
    };
});
```

Comment: Wow I think it was a bad question.. But thank you very much for your answer. it works.